# Paragraph footnotes with memoir and multicol

Tags: footnotes, memoir, multicol

I have a `memoir` document that is using `multicol` to get two columns.

If I have footnotes that are not on the last page, they don't `\paragraphfootnotes` correctly.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\paragraphfootnotes
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{cat}
\lipsum*[2]\footnote{dog}
\lipsum*[3]\footnote{A footnote with slightly more text in it showing that it goes unto the other side.}
\lipsum*[4]\footnote{Ibid.}
\lipsum*[5]\footnote{snake}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out the last `\lipsum` they work, or if you remove `\paragraphfootnotes` then they correctly span the entire width. Is there a way to get paragraph footnotes with `multicol`?